# Trying to load text file into an array, getting a seg fault. Any ideas why?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

The task of this function is fairly straightforward. Given an array of char*, a pointer to a file, and a maximum word size, it reads through the file and copies each word one by one into the char* array. Since there's one word per line in the file, it makes sense to use `\n` as the break between words. So with that in mind, the code should be fairly simple to interpret:

```
void loadDictionary(char* strDictionary[], FILE* filePointer, int nMaxLetters)
{
    int nNameCount= 0, nCursor = 0;
    char* strCurrent;
    char cCurrent;

    //allocate space for a word
    strCurrent = malloc(nMaxLetters * sizeof(char));

    while ((cCurrent = fgetc(filePointer)) != EOF) {

        if(cCurrent != '\n')
        {
            strCurrent[nCursor] = cCurrent;
            nCursor++;

        } else { //then we've reached the end of the line (word)

            //add null termination to string
            strCurrent[nCursor] = '\0'; //SEG FAULT

            //copy string to dictionary
            memcpy(strDictionary[nNameCount], strCurrent, strlen(strCurrent)+1);

            //increment count
            nNameCount++;

            //reset the cursor
            nCursor = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This code generates a segmentation fault at the line where I call `strCurrent[nCursor] = '\0';`. I'm not sure why, because on the face of it, it seems like this operation should be no different from the operation in the other block, where I call `strCurrent[nCursor] = cCurrent;`. strCurrent should have allocated more than enough space to store all necessary characters. So, I'm somewhat at a loss. Help me figure this one out, guys.

Note: I think I would probably have an easier time using `fgets` instead of `fgetc` to accomplish this task. I might well switch to that; however, since I have encountered an error I don't understand, I don't want to leave it alone until I've understood it.

EDIT:

Someone pointed out that the error might occur in the `memcpy` operation, possibly due to `strDictionary` being improperly allocated. Here's the `main` block where `strDictionary` gets allocated. Perhaps I have made an error:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char** strDictionary;
    FILE* filePointer;
    int nResults = 0, nLines = 0, nNumLines, nMaxChars, i;

    filePointer = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    //obtain the number of lines and the maximum word size of the dictionary
    countLines(filePointer, &nNumLines, &nMaxChars);

    //allocate memory for strDictionary
    strDictionary = malloc(nNumLines * nMaxChars * sizeof(char));
    printf("%d words in dictionary. Longest word is %d letters\n",
            nNumLines, nMaxChars);
    //Output here correctly prints: 1000 and 21

    //reset the file pointer (not sure if this is a necessary step, but oh well)
    filePointer = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    //load dictionary into memory
    loadDictionary(strDictionary, filePointer, nMaxChars);
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%dth element of dictionary: %s\n", i, strDictionary[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2:

OK, I decided to use `fgets()` instead of `fgetc()` to greatly simplify my function. I've also done what I thought was a correct `malloc()` operation for `strDictionary`. However, I'm still getting a seg fault. Here's the updated code:

```
void loadDictionary(char* strDictionary[], FILE* filePointer, int nMaxLetters)
{
    printf("Call to loadDictionary. nMaxLetters = %d\n", nMaxLetters);
    int nWordCount= 0, nCursor = 0;
    char* strCurrent;
    char cCurrent;

    strCurrent = malloc(nMaxLetters); //allocate space for a word


    while (fgets(strCurrent, nMaxLetters, filePointer) != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(strDictionary[nWordCount], strCurrent, strlen(strCurrent)+1);
        nWordCount++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char** strDictionary;
    FILE* filePointer;
    int nResults = 0, nLines = 0, nNumLines, nMaxChars, i;
    filePointer = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    //count the lines in the file (works fine)
    countLines(filePointer, &nNumLines, &nMaxChars);

    //allocate space for the dictionary
    strDictionary = malloc(nNumLines * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i<nLines; i++)
        strDictionary[i] = malloc(nMaxChars * sizeof(char));
    printf("%d words in dictionary. Longest word is %d letters\n",
            nNumLines, nMaxChars);

    //load dictionary into array
    filePointer = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    loadDictionary(strDictionary, filePointer, nMaxChars);
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%dth element of dictionary: %s\n", i, strDictionary[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you might want to check the value of 'nCursor' when it segfaults. ps there is no need to do sizeof(char) it's about the only size that is defined in C

Comment: Do you know if its on the first word it reads in? How long is the maximum line, how big is nMaxLetters?

Comment: Perhaps your code is segfaulting on a line that has nMaxLetters on it, and you didn't account for also including the terminating null character.

Comment: I suspect it might be the line `memcpy(strDictionary[nNameCount], strCurrent, strlen(strCurrent)+1);` where it segfaults. Have you allocated enough space to all elements of `strDictionary`?

Comment: I suspect it might the `malloc(nMaxLetters * sizeof(char));` you aren't allocating +1 for the null-byte-terminator.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, yes I know that but for pedantic reasons I like to always use sizeof() in malloc. :)

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, that line might be at fault, but it shouldn't be. strDictionary has been allocated by a previous malloc call outside of this function. But I'll make sure that's not where the error is, because it's a likely place. Thanks.

Comment: @limp_chimp You need not only allocate `strDictionary`, you also need to allocate `for(i = 0; i < strDictLen; ++i) { strDictionary[i] = malloc(enough); if (!strDictionary[i]) yell(); }` so the entries point to memory `memcpy` is allowed to copy to. Did you do that?

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks!! Looking at my code (which I just posted), it seems I didn't do that. So the proper way to do it would be to first set `strDictionary = malloc(nLines * sizeof(char*));`, and then iterate `nLines` times, each time malloc'ing space for each word. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Another option would be to `malloc` in `loadDictionary`, that would allow you to `malloc` just what's needed (`nCursor+1`).

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
char cCurrent;
...
while ((cCurrent = fgetc(filePointer)) != EOF) {
```

You are truncating the `fgetc()`'s value of type `int` to `char`. This may lead to the while condition not correctly recognizing `EOF`. `cCurrent` has to be `int`.

Here:

```
//allocate space for a word
strCurrent = malloc(nMaxLetters * sizeof(char));
```

`nMaxLetters` has to account for one extra character representing the string NUL terminator. Is it accounted for?

Btw, `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Now, this parameter declaration:

```
char* strDictionary[]
```

is equivalent to this:

```
char** strDictionary
```

or, IOW, a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. That's because in C, arrays are never passed as parameters, only pointers to their first elements are, despite the deceptive syntax with the brackets suggesting something is an array.

This line:

```
memcpy(strDictionary[nNameCount], strCurrent, strlen(strCurrent)+1);
```

is going to take `nNameCount`'th pointer to a `char` and write character data where it points to.

But does the calling function allocate at least as many string buffers (of length `nMaxLetters`) as there are going to be lines in the file? Does it populate some array of pointers to char with the pointers to these buffers before passing this array into `loadDictionary()`? IOW, this code is expecting the caller to do something like this:

```
#define nMaxEntries 1000

char* dictionary[nMaxEntries];
int i;
FILE* f;

...

for (i = 0; i < nMaxEntries; i++)
  dictionary[i] = malloc(nMaxLetters);

loadDictionary(dictionary, f, nMaxLetters);
```

Memory allocation failures must be checked in the above code. Also, I'd strongly suggest passing `nMaxEntries` into or using it in `loadDictionary()` so you don't overrun the array of pointers if the file has more lines than `nMaxEntries`. `nNameCount` should not grow beyond `nMaxEntries`.

**UPDATE** to the updated question...

Here:

```
char** strDictionary;
...
strDictionary = malloc(nNumLines * nMaxChars * sizeof(char));
```

You are not creating an array of pointers to `char` as `loadDictionary()` expects per the above analysis, you are creating a 2d array of `char`. And because of that the segfault most probably occurs not on this line:

```
 strCurrent[nCursor] = '\0'; //SEG FAULT
```

but on the very next one, which may not be apparent in the debugger until you zoom in and look at the disassembly of the code:

```
 //copy string to dictionary
 memcpy(strDictionary[nNameCount], strCurrent, strlen(strCurrent)+1);
```

**UPDATE2:**

I don't understand why you now allocate space for `nNumLines` pointers:

```
strDictionary = malloc(nNumLines * sizeof(char*));
```

but of those `nNumLines` pointers you initialize `nLines` pointers (and `nLines` never becomes anything other than 0 if I'm reading your latest code correctly):

```
for (i = 0; i<nLines; i++)
    strDictionary[i] = malloc(nMaxChars * sizeof(char));
```

What's the trick? Typo?